# What's the difference between work done and work obtained?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, conventions

I'm trying to understand work obtained in the context of gravitational potential energy. 
It's stated as the **work obtained** when an object is moved from infinity to a point
$$U = -GMm/r.$$

Comment: Looks like bad wording. It probably means *work done* by gravity, which is the negative of the gravitational *potential energy obtained* in the processes.

Comment: What book offers this terminology?

Comment: @KyleKanos I suspect translation problem.

Comment: Google can help a lot to learn the proper English terminology. Simply google for texts about this and check, which words are they using. If your question will be closed, don't worry, but also add some details. With your edit a reopen vote will be started on the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying intuition is that when you drop an object from a given height h, the object will accelerate towards the ground thus converting the potential energy into kinetic energy. During this process we have "done nothing", the object is accelerated without our doing thus we obtain work and reduce the potential of the object. If we lifted the object a certain height we would need to invest energy and thus do work.

---

A more specific example: We choose our potential to be such that it vanishes for $h = 0\; m$. For convenience $g = 10\; \frac{m}{s^2}$. If we have a ball of mass $m = 2\;kg$ at an initial height of $h = 10 \;m$ the potential energy of the ball is given by $E_{pot}= m\cdot g \cdot h = 2 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \;[J] = 200 \;[J]$. When the ball drops it does this on its own and converts the potential energy. If we would like to reverse this process we would need to invest energy (meaning we have to do work). (Note that this relies on the approximation that the (gravitational-)force exerted on the mass is constant and thus only valid for small enough h)

---

A more general derivation:
The potential energy for gravity is $$U(r) =m V(r)$$ where $m$ is the mass of the object and $V$ the gravitational potential. For a unit test mass $m_t =1$ we have that $$V(r) = \frac{W}{m_t} = \frac{1}{m_t} \int_{\infty}^r \frac{Gm_tM}{\bar{r}^2}d\bar{r} = -\frac{1}{m_t}\frac{Gm_tM}{r} = -\frac{GM}{r} $$
Using the formula for the potential energy we obtain that $$U = - \frac{GMm}{r}$$ just as the formula desired. (The example above should give you and intuition for the minus. Throughout the whole problem spherical symmetry was assumed.)

Comment: what;s the difference between gravitational potential V and gravitational potential energy U?

Comment: @JacobP.J The gravitational potential V is basicalls the potential energy U at a certain point r for an object of mass m = 1.